# MediaPlayer setDisplay when returning to an activity not working

Tags: android, service, media-player

I want to play video with MediaPlayer in the background so when the user leave my app he will still hear the audio and when he is returning to the app he will see the video. I managed to do the first part with Service that plays the MediaPlayer, but I have a problem in the second part. When I leave the app and return the video does not show in the SurfaceView.

When the user return I created new Surface, so I tried this:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(mService!=null && mService.player.isPlaying()){          
        try {
            mService.player.setDisplay(holder);
            mService.player.prepare();
            mService.player.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }       
}
```

While `mService` is my Service and he holds the MediaPlayer `player`.

In my research I saw this post:
[Black screen when returning to video playback activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347924/black-screen-when-returning-to-video-playback-activity-in-android)

But this was posted a year ago so maybe anyone has any different and new answer.

EDIT:
I forgot to say that the video is streaming, so reset is not good option (i tried :)).

is it possible to save the SurfaceView in the Service and when the user return to take the view and add it dynamically to the current layout?

Answer (score 0):

When you first launch Activity: onResume()->onSurfaceCreated()->onSurfaceChanged().
When you leave Activity: onPause()->onSurfaceDestroyed()

So i you leave your app, surface will be automatically destroy, you also can not save surfaceview in service.
Remember, if you want to show video again, surfaceview and holder callback must created again in `onStart` in case your home or lockscreen pressed

```
surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
holder.setFixedSize(800, 480);
holder.addCallback(this);
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```